# Making an array of string in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I'm trying to make an array of string, but can't get it to run correctly. Here is what I have.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim wordArray() As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'increase the size of string array by one, by setting the new upperBound at the current Length

    'use Preserve so that string currently in the array are not overwritten with Nothing

    ReDim Preserve wordArray(wordArray.Length)

    'use an TextBox to get the name of the new string from the user

    'assign this name (which is a String) to the last element of the string array

    wordArray(wordArray.GetUpperBound(0)) = TextBox2.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

How about a `List(Of String)`? No `ReDim` required here.

```
Private wordList As New List(Of String)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  wordList.Add(textbox2.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: And you can always convert wordList to an array by invoking wordList.ToArray()

Answer (score 1):

For Fixed-size array:

```
Dim strCDRack(0 to 2) As String 

strCDRack(0) = "Deftones"
strCDRack(1) = "Tool"
strCDRack(2) = "Disturbed"
```

For Dynamic array:

```
Dim strCDRack() As String 

ReDim strCDRack(0 to 2) As String 

strCDRack(0) = "Deftones"
strCDRack(1) = "Tool"
strCDRack(2) = "Disturbed"
```

For expanding the Dynamic array:

```
Dim strCDRack() As String 

ReDim strCDRack(0 to 2) As String 

strCDRack(0) = "Deftones"
strCDRack(1) = "Tool"
strCDRack(2) = "Disturbed" 

ReDim Preserve strCDRack(0 to 3) As String 

strCDRack(3) = "Charlotte Church"
```

For more info about VB arrays checkout this [link](http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm)..

Answer (score 0):

Use a list!

```
Dim StringArray As New List(Of [String])()
```

And in the click handler:

```
StringArray.Add(TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: No need to Escape `String` here since it is not attempting to use as the variable.

Comment: used a code converter from C#, I don't personally write VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Collections` here like `List(Of String)`, it grows as the number of element grows. No need to maintain size  yourself. Also the problem might at your end is, when you `ReDim` try to increase your array size.

`ReDim Preserve wordArray(wordArray.Length + 1)`